# Which software can I use to keep a track of color percent?

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, graphics2d, graphical-logo

I am designing a logo with 5 shapes of 5 different colors each, one inside another.[My Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNiZW.png)

I want every color to be present in the logo in the equal proportion (20% each). Which software should I use which either tells me real-time percent of all colors or draws me such a logo if I provide it all five colors & shapes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work, if your colors are homogenous:
1. Convert to grayscale
2. Document the different grayscale values
3. For each color, count the pixels
4. Divide each pixelcount by the total amount of pixels in that image

Now you have the percentages for each color

You can use any programming language to do that